# How to check or validate the textbox entered date is in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

How to check or validate the textbox entered date is in `DD/MM/YYYY` format?

Comment: Please don't use DD/MM/YYYY format. There's an international standard, YYYY-MM-DD (ISO8601)

Comment: Better yet, use a calendar control rather than a textbox.

Comment: @Pavel: Try telling that to the general public, who are used to writing dates in their local format

Comment: @MPritch: Agree. My web app customers would send me very far if I'll ask them to write not how does the used to write but following ISO 8601

Comment: @MPritch: Though that is the local format in some countries.

Comment: @Pavel: A UI should be user-focused and it's down to the developer to decide what method of input to use as a result of customer requirements. The international disparity in date formats isn't going away so we simply need to accomodate and not force users.

Comment: First, I think you should either support all local formats or none. In the former case, OS settings should be respected. Also, there's a certain degree of wisdom you can impose on the user.

Comment: @CylonCat Problem with a calendar control is that i cannot type a date into it (i have to navigate the date sections)

Comment: @Pavel: Sorry, that is a ridiculous statement!  Application design is USER-centric, not ISO-centric.  My users would cry if I enforced the YYYY-MM-DD standard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Markup:

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Date was in incorrect format" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime d;
    e.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
}
```

if you want to allow several formats and only them, use next:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value, new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" }, CultureInfo.InvarinatCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using a regular expression validator.  The regular expression below checks for DD/MM/YYYY but of course there is no way to distinguish if something like 01 is DD or MM.  Otherwise it does the trick.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                ControlToValidate="txtDate"     
                                ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime Result;
DateTimeFormatInfo info = new DateTimeFormatInfo ( );
CultureInfo culture;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ( "en-US" );
info.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
if ( DateTime.TryParse ( StrDate, info, DateTimeStyles.None, out Result ) )
{
  return StrDate;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here. Please add a description of why your solution answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) to check that the entered value is within set parameters.
I.e. 13/12/2001 is valid but 12/13/2001 is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom Validator to check just about anything in text box, but it might be easier to use [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) to check if the text can be converted to a date.

I found an example (in VB but easy enough to read and translate to C#) here: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/validation/default.aspx

However, using some sort of date picker control might be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off using a calendar control, but if you want to check the date string anyway, use the following code can be used to validate that the is in DD/MM/YYYY format.

```
DateTime dt;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(texbox.Text, new  System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt))
{
    // text is not in the correct format
}
```

Comment: en-GB = British English culture settings. It uses DD/MM/YYYY format

Comment: seems easier to specify the string format, en-GB may allow other variations as well.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use a regexvalidator for a first quick test ("does it look like it could be a date") client-side. And then a CustomValidator with a serverside event that tries to perform a DateTime.Parse with my format, to rule out dates like "29 feb 2010".

Personally I don't trust the CompareValidator here, because I don't know for sure what format it uses (but that can be because I didn't investigate enough).

Answer (score -2):

You can't. User some kind of datetime picker instead. Example [here](http://it.my/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).

Comment: Probably because it *can* be validated. (not me downvoting btw)

Comment: No, it can't. Unless you have some magic computer that can read peoples minds. 01/12/2010 = dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: ambiguous dates are a weakness of this approach and could lead to problems, but it's still possible to implement a validator. I agree that a date control is a better idea, but if there are requirements to have a text box and allow entry in this format then it is at least worth validating that the text forms a valid date.

Comment: I guess it depends how you define validation then. If you enter mm/dd and your dd/mm validator passes the input, then I'd say your validator doesn't work. The job of validation is to return "yes/no", not "maybe/no"